# Paragraph page number misalignment in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, paragraphs, tocloft

I am using the Ph.D. dissertation .cls file. When I create a paragraph there is a misalignment in the paragraph page number in TOC.
[image: TOC]

Below is the minimal code:

```
\documentclass[final]{USC-Thesis_Minimal}
\usepackage[lofdepth,lotdepth,caption=false]{subfig}
\begin{document}
\title{Some title}

\author{Some Name}
\major{Some Engineering}
\month{May}
\year{2019}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\maketitle

% Table Of Contents
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

% List of tables
\listoftables

% List of figures
\listoffigures


% Begin Body
\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter 1} 
\section{A very long section, very long text section}
\subsection{A very long subsection, very long text subsection}
\subsubsection{A very long subsubsection Very long text subsubsection}
\paragraph{A long paragraph}


\end{document}
```

Below is the relevant part of the cls file.

```
%Margins of Table of Contents - so that the page listings for toc do 
%not align with page number 
\cftsetrmarg{0.7in}
\newlength{\numtomarg}
\setlength{\numtomarg}{0.2in}
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\hspace{\numtomarg}\mbox{}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\hspace{\numtomarg}\mbox{}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\hspace{\numtomarg}\mbox{}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecafterpnum}{\hspace{\numtomarg}\mbox{}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\hspace{\numtomarg}\mbox{}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubfigafterpnum}{\hspace{\numtomarg}\mbox{}}
\renewcommand{\cfttabafterpnum}{\hspace{\numtomarg}\mbox{}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubtabafterpnum}{\hspace{\numtomarg}\mbox{}}
```

I couldn't find an alternative for the paragraph. Similar to:

```
\renewcommand{\cftparagraphafterpnum}{\hspace{\numtomarg}\mbox{}}
```

Here is the [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlFYM4jwmzqrtLRMns36H70YejeC9w?e=9OiwNf) to the class file. Can somebody help me to fix this issue, please?

Answer (score 1):

Using the below LaTeX command did the trick:

```
\renewcommand{\cftparaafterpnum}{\hspace{\numtomarg}\mbox{}}
```