# Paragraph number misaligned when included in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I want to include paragraphs in my table of contents for my dissertation. However, when I do so, the paragraph number is misaligned compared to the rest. The numbers for the preceding sections are set to occur a line below the end of the whitespace following the above section number, while the paragraph number begins before that whitespace.

[image]

What I would like is for the paragraph number to occur directly below the first letter of the above subsubsection number, as shown in the edited image below.

[image]

How can I do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{blah}
    \section{blah}
    \subsection{blah}
    \subsubsection{blah}
    \paragraph{blah}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that this is not the same issue as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574225/paragraph-page-number-misalignment-in-table-of-contents, which has to do with misalignment of the page number. For me the page number is correctly aligned, but the paragraph number is not.

Comment: so a paragraph 12.12.12.12.12 would be indented more than 1.1.1.1.1 or would you want a fixed indent big enough for all levels to have 2 (or 3?) digits?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question? I want the start of the paragraph number to be aligned with the left edge of the subsubsection title immediately above it. So the length of the paragraph number shouldn't affect indentation, but the length of the subsubsection title should (in reality though, I don't have any more than one digit per level for any section, subsection, etc., so if there's a way to take advantage of that I'm open to it).

Comment: Do you *really* need such level of detail in the table of contents? And also in the numbering? The table of contents will be awful and not really informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You want the indent at each stage to be increased by the width allocated for the number at the previous stage

```
\documentclass{book}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\makeatletter
%                                            level indent numwidth
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline      {1}{1.5em} {2.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline   {2}{3.8em} {3.2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em} {4.1em}}
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline    {4}{11.1em}{5.0em}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{blah}
    \section{blah}
    \subsection{blah}
    \subsubsection{blah}
    \paragraph{blah}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You were right to ask if any of the levels would have a value greater than 9.  I've never managed to make such a toc look decent if more than two levels deep.  (I would usually align on the dot that preceded the first element that contained more than one digit, or on the first dot if there were more than 9 chapters.)

Answer (score 2):

A similar output using the package `titletoc`. Tested with double digit chapter numbers, just in case.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{showframe}% show the margins

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}
[2em] % left margin from left page margin
{\bfseries}
{\contentslabel{2em}} % before title with label
{\hspace*{-2em}}% before title without label
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{section}
[4.5em] %increase the previous + space for new number
{}
{\contentslabel{2.5em}}
{\hspace*{-2.5em}}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsection}
[7.7em]%increase the previous + space for new number
{}
{\contentslabel{3.2em}}
{\hspace*{-3.2em}}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{subsubsection}
[11.7em]%increase the previous + space for new number
{}
{\contentslabel{4em}}
{\hspace*{-4em}}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\titlecontents{paragraph}
[16.5em]%increase the previous + space for new number
{}
{\contentslabel{4.8em}}
{\hspace*{-4.8em}}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \setcounter{chapter}{20}
    \chapter{blah c}
    \section{blah s}
    \subsection{blah sbs}
    \subsubsection{blah sbsbs}
    \paragraph{blah p}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: After trying this one in the actual use case, it led to the ToC being unable to contain a page break. It would compile, but it would run off the page and the full contents wouldn't show. Not sure why, but wanted to give a heads-up.